# Effect of weights column in h2o DRF

Tags: random-forest, h2o

The [h2o documentation](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tutte/1/docs-website/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/weights_column.html) states for the `weights_column` option that

> This option specifies the column in a training frame to be used when determining weights. Weights are per-row observation weights and do not increase the size of the data frame. This is typically the number of times a row is repeated, but non-integer values are also supported. During training, rows with higher weights matter more, due to the larger loss function pre-factor.

I am particularly interested in the effect of the weights column on the regression trees of `DRF` (random forest).
I find the description "This is typically the number of times a row is repeated" confusing. While they say that the frame's size is actually not increased, it insinuates that rows with higher/lower weight get over/under-sampled (when the per-tree training data is selected according to `sample_rate`). However, looking at the h2o source code on github, this does not seem to be the case.
The relevant parts of the code where the weights are used are in [DHistogram.java](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/tree/DHistogram.java) and read

```
double wy = weight * y;
double wyy = wy * y;  // This is the correct implementation.
int b = bin(col_data);
_vals[3*b + 0] += weight;
_vals[3*b + 1] += wy;
_vals[3*b + 2] += wyy;
```

This indicates that the weights are only used for calculating the number of *weighted* rows (`_vals[3*b + 0]`) and for the *weighted* sum of squared errors (via `_vals[3*b + 1]` and `_vals[3*b + 2]`, see [DTree.java](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/tree/DTree.java)).

Furthermore, I did some tests with different weights in `R`. I trained different `DRF` models, each with homogeneous weights across all observations but with different weight magnitude across the models. My suspicion that the weights are only used for the weighted row count and weighted squared errors seems to be confirmed.

```
library(h2o)

h2o.init()

#different weights for each model
iris$weight0=0.5
iris$weight1=1
iris$weight2=2
irisH=as.h2o(iris)
predNames=setdiff(colnames(irisH),c("Sepal.Length","weight2","weight1","weight0"))
exludeLinesRegex="(.*DRF_model_R_.*)|(.*AUTOGENERATED.*)|(.*UUID.*)|(.*weight.*)"
pojoList=list()

#train 3 models, each with different weights magnitude
for (i in 0:2) {
    weightColName=paste0("weight",i)
    tmpRf=h2o.randomForest(y="Sepal.Length",
                           x=predNames,
                           training_frame = irisH,
                           seed = 1234,
                           ntrees = 10,
                           #min_rows has to be adjusted-it refers to weighted rows
                           min_rows= 20*irisH[1,weightColName],
                           max_depth = 3,
                           mtries = 4,
                           weights_column = weightColName)
    tmpPojo=capture.output(h2o.download_pojo(tmpRf))
    pojoList[[length(pojoList)+1]]=tmpPojo[!grepl(exludeLinesRegex,tmpPojo)]
}

h2o.shutdown(FALSE)

# all forests are the same
length(unique(pojoList))
# 1
```

As one can see above, all 3 forests are the same despite having different weight magnitudes. The only adjustment that had to be done is `min_rows` because it refers to a weighted row number.
If the rows really would get over/undersampled, I would expect to see (small) differences between the models.

My questions are therefore:

1. Are the weights used anywhere else than for calculating the number of weighted rows and sum of squared errors?
2. Are regression `DRF` models generally invariant under homogeneous scaling of the weights, i.e., if I multiply the weights column by a scalar `a>0` and adjust `min_rows` accordingly, do the models stay the same? (As shown in the R code example above.)
3. If yes, does this also hold for forests with classification trees and `GBM` models?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually, weights can indicate which rows are important to get right, or indicate
which rows to replicate or compress. Including the `weights_column`, however, does not change the actual
size of your dataset; it only affects the mathematical calculations for DRF.

Note: H2O trains regression trees, regardless of whether you are solving a classification or regression problem.

**Bulleted Details**

- The `weights_column` does not affect the sampling rate.
- multiplying the weights by a factor will not change the outcome (i.e. a weights column of all 1s is the same as a weights column of all 2s)
- weights are used in several locations here are a few examples:

  - The first node in each tree
  - The loss function, which is used to decide on which feature to split at each internal node.
  - The terminal nodes.
  - All performance metric calculations.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding your second bullet point "multiplying ..." - I guess that min_rows must be adjusted (like I wrote and tested in my OP) in order for the outcome to stay the same if the weights are multiplied by a constant.

Comment: @cryo111 yes you are correct, you would need to adjust the min_rows.

Comment: @Lauren Should you provide some additional info about how the weight column interacts with the loss function?